# Batch file wait for entered command

Tags: batch-file

So, is it possible, to to this:

- Start a .bat
- Have that bat wait for a written command
- On command- run it, then return to the waiting stage

Comment: Yes it is - where did you get stuck?

Comment: Upvoting because I'm not a smarty pants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1 of your question is a given.

For part 2 you could use the built-in command `set` with the `/P` option or one of the many options discussed by Rob van der Woude: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/userinput.php.

For part 3 of your questions, use a loop, such as `goto :loop`. It certainly would be smart to have an exit option, too.

Comment: Working, ty accepted this as it has a big reference site in it.

Comment: you write " It certainly would be smart to have an exit option, too." <-- ctrl-c!

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
:a
set /p thecommand=give command:
%thecommand%
goto :a
```

Comment: This works! TY!